# How many people in the family

Tags: riddle, family

Imagine a family with:

> Mother
>
> Mother
>
> Daughter
>
> Daughter
>
> Grandmother
>
> Granddaughter

How many people are in the family?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Three

This is because

> there is one grandmother/mother to a daughter who is a mom and a daughter who has a daughter who is the granddaughter.

Answer (score 1):

Minimum:

> Alice - Beth's Mother, Cat's Grandmother
>  Beth - Alice's Daughter, Cat's Mother
>  Cat - Beth's Daughter, Alice's Granddaughter

Answer (score 0):

> Only 3. 
>  A grandmother is an old lady, her daughter a middle-aged wonen and small girl. 
>  The old lady is the mother of the middle aged women. The middle aged women is the daughter of the small girl. So we have two mothers and two daughters. 
>  The old lady is the grandmother of the small girl. Thus the girl is the granddaughter of the old women.